# Check if value is false in handlebar helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have created a handlebar helper which gives true or false values. How can I check if the value is false and render HTML. I tried using unless but it's not working. I don't want to give any else condition.

```
ifTrue = false

{{#unless ifTrue}}
   <p> Print when not true.</p>
{{/unless}}
```

Comment: `#unless` would do exactly what you want. If it is not working, there is something else wrong in your code. Perhaps the value of `ifTrue` is a string?

Comment: What is meant under "handlebar helper"? Can you share the code?

Comment: Unless false should do it :/ any chance you can make a reproduction?